# How to download an Image file after applying filter on it?

Tags: javascript, html, imagedownload

I am a beginner. I am just making a practice project. Here I used these codes for drag and drop an image upload on a `<div>` and apply filters on it (it works fine till now). I didn't use a canvas. I know the process of how to download from the canvas but don't know how to download from a `<div>` after uploading on it as `appendChild`. I don't know jquery or other kinds of stuff. I just want to download my picture after applying a filter on it. I am giving HTML and JS down below. If you know it please help me with code and a little bit of explanation, I will be grateful. I am not adding CSS code as this question doesn't relate to it.

```js
const dropzone = document.querySelector(".drop__zone");
const fileinput = document.getElementById("mainup");
const dropzone2 = document.querySelector(".dropzone");
const img = new Image();
const downloadBtn = document.getElementById("maindown");

const filtercontrols = document.querySelectorAll('.filter__slider');
let fileName = "";

fileinput.addEventListener('change',()=>{
                           
                          
  
 const file2 = document.getElementById("mainup").files[0];
 
  const reader2 = new FileReader();

 
  if (file2) {
   
   fileName = file2.name;
    
    reader2.readAsDataURL(file2);
  }

  
    reader2.onload = ()=>{
        
        img.src = reader2.result;
        img.style.maxHeight = "480px";
        img.style.maxWidth = "640px";
        dropzone.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      dropzone2.style.display = "none";
        dropzone.style.border = "none";
        
       dropzone.appendChild(img);
   return false;     
    };
   
 });




    
    


     dropzone.ondragover = function (){
    
        this.className = "drop__zone can__over";
         dropzone2.style.display = "none";
         
        return false;
    };

dropzone.ondragleave = function(){
 
    this.className = "drop__zone";
    dropzone2.style.display = "block";
    
    return false;
};

dropzone.ondrop = function (e){
     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.className = "drop__zone";
    dropzone2.style.display = "none";
     dropzone2.style.border = "none";
    
    update(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
};

var update = function(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
    reader.onload = ()=>{
       
        img.src = reader.result;
        img.style.maxHeight = "480px";
        img.style.maxWidth = "640px";
        dropzone.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      
        
       dropzone.appendChild(img);
   return false;     
    };
   
};


function filter(){
    var computedfilters = "";
    
    
    filtercontrols.forEach(function(item){
        computedfilters += item.getAttribute('data-filter') + '(' + item.value + item.getAttribute('data-scale') + ') ';
        
    });
    
    

    img.style.filter = computedfilters;
     
     
};
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="bgimg"></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="file:///G:/HTML%20CSS%20JAVA/Project%20Filter/filter.html">
            <h1>Filtaro</h1>
        </a></div>




    <div class="intro">
        <h2>Welcome to Filtaro !</h2> <br>
        <p>Filter your images with different filters.No quality decrease ! Have Fun !</p>
    </div>



    <div class="drop__zone" id="drop__zone"></div>


    <div class="dropzone" id="drop__zone">
        <span class="dropzone__span">
            Drag a Image Here <br>or<br>
        </span><br>
        <input type="file" id="mainup" multiple="false" accept="image/*" class="fileinput">
        <label for="mainup" class="btn__label" id="lab1">Upload a Picture</label
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <input type="button" id="maindown">
        <label for="maindown" class="btn__label" id="lab2">Download</label></div>





    <div class="filter">
        <label for="blur" id="blur__label" class="filter__label">Blur</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="blur" data-scale="px" class="filter__slider" id="blur"><br>

        <label for="brightness" id="brightness__label" class="filter__label">Brightness</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="100" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="brightness" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="brightness"><br>

        <label for="contrast" id="contrast__label" class="filter__label">Contrast</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="100" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="contrast" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="contrast"><br>

        <label for="gray" id="gray__label" class="filter__label">Grayscale</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="grayscale" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="gray"><br>

        <label for="Hue" id="Hue__label" class="filter__label">Hue</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="hue-rotate" data-scale="deg" class="filter__slider" id="Hue"><br>

        <label for="inv" id="blur__label" class="filter__label">Invert</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="invert" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="inv"><br>

        <label for="opacity" id="opacity__label" class="filter__label">Opacity</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="100" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="opacity" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="opacity"><br>

        <label for="saturate" id="saturate__label" class="filter__label">Saturate</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="1" max="200" value="1" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="saturate" data-scale="" class="filter__slider" id="saturate"><br>

        <label for="sepia" id="sepia__label" class="filter__label">Sepia</label><br>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="0" step="1" onchange="filter()" data-filter="sepia" data-scale="%" class="filter__slider" id="sepia">



    </div>




    <script src="filter.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question.  The only way to save the image with such filters is to render it to the canvas and apply the filter to the canvas, as you mentioned you know how to do.  You could also use an `svg` element instead of canvas, or use the Screen Capture API to record the screen, but that wouldn't be easier than using the canvas.

Comment: okay. now I understand.Thanks.

Comment: One more thing I need to ask from you can I drag and drop an image on the canvas? because I tried that but couldn't figure it out that's why I switched to `<div>`.If you know it please let me know with an example.Thanks

Comment: Please open a new question and share the link here, I'll check it out and see if I can help.

Comment: Here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370669/how-to-drag-drop-and-preview-an-image-file-on-html-canvas-with-vanilla-javascr